# How to store ArrayList in Redis caching?

Tags: java, caching, redis

I am trying to store Arraylist values which coming from DB to Redis Client . But Redis have only Key/Value methods the Key/Value must be String format. How can i store Key as String and Values As Arraylist.

Answer (score 2):

> But Redis have only Key/Value methods the Key/Value must be String format

[Redis actually has very good support for storing values as lists](http://redis.io/commands#list), if that's what you want to do. Do that, if you want to do any sort of list operations on the value.

If you just want to store the list and retrieve it as a whole, then you want to just serialize it into a string prior to storing in Redis. In that case, encode the list as a JSON string (or any other serializing format) and store that in Redis. Then just GET it and deserialize when you want it back.

Answer (score 1):

YOu have to use the Map to store data with keys and values

```
  Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new Map<String, ArrayList<String>>();
  ArrayList<String> a= new  ArrayList<String>();
  a.add("Ganesh");
  map.put("Name", a);
```

Comment: I want cache my result  which came from Database. so we are using Redis caching mechanism. for example when same query triggers first it will check in caching if not then DB. if data available in Caching that will return t the client with out hitting the DB.

Comment: It's new new HashMap not new Map

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set for this

http://redis.io/commands/sadd

Add members to the set individually, or in an array in redis-cli like so:

```
sadd my_new_set a b c d e f g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with Redis based framework - [Redisson](https://redisson.org). It offers wrapped collections like `java.util.List`, `java.util.Set`, `java.util.Map` and many more.

Here is an example for `List`:

```
Config config = ...
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
List<String> list = redisson.getList("myList");
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");

list.remove("2");
```

It supports many popular codecs like `Jackson JSON`, `Avro`, `Amazon Ion`, `Smile`, `CBOR`, `MsgPack`, `Kryo`, `FST`, `LZ4`, `Snappy` and `JDK Serialization`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to store ArrayList in redis

```
 public void saveCollection(String key, Collection<String> object) {
        try {
            ListOperations<String, String> listOps = redisTemplate.opsForList();
            listOps.rightPushAll(key, object);
            LOGGER.info("Saving collection for key {} in Redis", key);
        } catch (RedisException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Redis Exception", e);
        }
    }
```